# Cypress: assertion error on json field comparison

Tags: json, automated-tests, cypress

i am trying to do assertion on a json. basically i have to compare two json:

```
        cy.get('h4#idParameters').each(($e, index, $list) => {
            const text = $e.text()
            expect(text).to.eq(parameters)

        })
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

in the assertion if I use "contain" instead of "eq" the result doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist a space after ":" char in the first parameter. These strings are not equal.

If you want to compare this as a string, ensure it does not have extra spaces, points, or is in a different order.

But the better approach is to compare as JSON. One interesting approach should be using the [deep-equal-in-any-order](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/deep-equal-in-any-order/) plugin. This plugin compares objects independent of it order. But first ensure to transform JSON strings to objects.

Answer (score 1):

in the end I solved it like this. Thanks for the advice @Erme.

```
        cy.get('h4#idParameters').each(($e, index, $list) => {
            const text = $e.text()
            var p1 = JSON.stringify(text)
            var p2 = JSON.stringify(parameters)
            p1=p1.replace(/\s/g, '');
            p2=p2.replace(/\s/g, '');
            p2 = p2.substr(1,p2.length)
            expect(p1).to.contain(p2)
        })
```